# Contador While infinito

Tags: java, condiciones, while

Estoy intentando hacer un bucle que muestre 3 veces en pantalla un resultado de una comprobación, mi duda surge ya que lo hace infinitamente y no es capaz de parar cuando llega a 3. He añadido un log para poder indentificarlo `log.debug("volvemos a intentar la peticion 3 veces");`.Muestro el código para que se vea lo que estoy haciendo.

```
            String status = null;
            int numero = 0;
            int numIntentos = 3;
            int threadSleep = 60000;
            while (numero <= numIntentos) {
                Thread.sleep(threadSleep);
                status = getConnectorReplies();
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(status)) {
                    if (status.equals("Ok")) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        log.debug("volvemos a intentar la peticion 3 veces");
                        numero++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Lo más seguro entonces es que no te esté entrando al if `(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(status))`, ya que solo incrementas `numero` si entra y no es "Ok"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la llamada a `(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(status))` devuelve siempre falso, el ciclo es infinito, pues el número nunca se incrementa.

Podrías dejar las dos condiciones en un solo `if`, de manera que el `numero` se incremente si alguna de las dos condiciones no se cumple, por ejemplo:

```
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(status) && status.equals("Ok")) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    log.debug("volvemos a intentar la peticion 3 veces");
                    numero++;
                }
```

Luego, ya que la condición del `while` es `(numero <= numIntentos)`, en realidad el ciclo se va a ejecutar hasta 4 veces, con lo que diría que estás *intentando* 4 veces.

Si lo que quieres es intentar solo 3, cambia la condicón a:

```
while (numero < numIntentos)
```

Para finalizar, sugiero un cambio de nombre de variables, pues de la manera expresada es confuso, que tal así:

```
    String status = null;
    int numeroIntentos = 0;
    int maximoIntentos = 3;
    int threadSleep = 60000;
    while (numeroIntentos < maximoIntentos) {
        Thread.sleep(threadSleep);
        status = getConnectorReplies();
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(status) && status.equals("Ok")) {
            break;
        } else {
            log.debug("volvemos a intentar la petición...");
            numeroIntentos++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la info, al final me decanto por este ya que me simplifico todo en un único if, saludos

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda. Veo que has realizado varias preguntas y no tienes ninguna respuesta marcada como aceptada. ¿Si sabes hacerlo? Es la idea del sitio. Revisa tus preguntas y considera marcar las respuestas de tu elección como aceptadas. Eso ayudará a futuros visitantes a identificar con rapidez la respuesta que (mejor) te ha servido a ti, como autor de la pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Veo también que tienes auto-respuestas, y esas también las puedes marcar como aceptadas.

Answer (score 1):

He modificado ligeramente el código para que la condición se ejecute siempre que no se salga antes de llegar a ella, de esta manera no hace falta usar `else` y se ejecutará el incremento SI o SI siempre que no se haya salido antes:

```
String status = null;
int numero = 0;
int numIntentos = 3;
int threadSleep = 60000;
while (numero <= numIntentos) {
    Thread.sleep(threadSleep);
    status = getConnectorReplies();
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(status)) 
        if (status.equals("Ok"))
            break;
    //Si no se ha salido antes de llegar aquí, incrementa numero
    log.debug("volvemos a intentar la peticion 3 veces");
    numero++;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información, lo he probado y funciona perfectamente!